# Android Native Component GridLayout - inappropriate cell sizing

Tags: android, react-native

EDIT: As near as I can tell, the `GridLayout`'s size is set by whatever it would be if all the cells were a single column. So is it just not updating after everything is added?

[image]

I am trying to expose GridLayout to React Native, and I'm finding this bizarre issue where the table sets its size to the size of the first child, and then every other child renders outside of the table.

[image: Cells render outside table]

And the only thing I can find that even gets the cells to render inside the table is to set their `layoutParams.width` and `layoutParams.height` to 0 and give them a positive `weight`, but then that refuses to wrap the contents.

[image: Cells render inside table but still too big]

What the heck is going on???

NOTE: This is is the opposite of the most common question I saw where people couldn't figure out how to get all columns to be the same width or some percentage. I want the columns to shrink to match the content.

[Here's the full repo](https://github.com/MacKenzieHnC/Table)

App.tsx

```js
import * as React from 'react';

import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { TableView } from '@mackenziehnc/table';

export default function App() {
  const data = ['Cell 1', 'Cell 2', 'Cell 3', 'Cell 4', 'Cell 5', 'Cell 6'];
  return (
    <View style={{ width: 200, borderWidth: 3, borderColor: 'red' }}>
      <TableView>
        {data.map((child, index) => (
          <View
            key={index}
            style={{ borderWidth: 1, flexShrink: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}
          >
            <Text style={{ flexShrink: 1, borderWidth: 1 }}>{child}</Text>
          </View>
        ))}
      </TableView>
    </View>
  );
```

TableViewNativeComponent.ts

```js
import codegenNativeComponent from 'react-native/Libraries/Utilities/codegenNativeComponent';
import type { ViewProps } from 'react-native';

export default codegenNativeComponent<ViewProps>('TableView');
```

TableViewManager.java

```java
package com.mackenziehnc.table;

import com.facebook.react.module.annotations.ReactModule;
import com.facebook.react.uimanager.ThemedReactContext;

@ReactModule(name = TableViewManager.NAME)
public class TableViewManager extends com.mackenziehnc.table.TableViewManagerSpec<TableView> {

  public static final String NAME = "TableView";

  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return NAME;
  }

  @Override
  public TableView createViewInstance(ThemedReactContext context) {
    return new TableView(context);
  }
}
```

TableView.java

```java
package com.mackenziehnc.table;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.GridLayout;

public class TableView extends GridLayout {

  public TableView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setColumnCount(2); // I know this is bad, this is temporary
  }

  @Override
  public void addView(View child, int index) {
    GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
    params.rowSpec = GridLayout.spec(index / getColumnCount());
    params.columnSpec = GridLayout.spec(index % getColumnCount());
    child.setLayoutParams(params);
    super.addView(child, index);
  }
}
```